# Unable to get value of subject field of the draft using Webdriver in Yahoo draft mail

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, yahoo-mail

I've created draft letter in [Yahoo mail](https://mg.mail.yahoo.com/) and then get to this draft letter page.
Now I'd like to get value of the Subject field using C# and Selenium Webdriver.
I used the following code, but it returns empty string :

```
string subjectLocator = "//*[@id='subject-field']";
string actualSubject = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(subjectLocator)).GetAttribute("Value");
```

Using of Text property instead of `GetAttribute` method also doesn't help.

How to get value of the subject field in yahoo draft letter using `Selenium` `Webdriver` and `C#`?

http://prnt.sc/bye5ae - html code

Comment: have you tried `GetAttribute("innerHTML")`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, there is also empty string returned.

Comment: can you please paste HTML code here for us to look at?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/bye5ae please take a look at the screenshot.

Comment: you got no exception? no error message? Simply returns Null?

Comment: There is no exeption, and not null, but "" is returned - empty string.

Comment: Have you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present...may be it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I seeing you are using to get value from subject field as `.GetAttribute("Value")`, here only problem is to passing attribute property as `Value` which should be `value` means `v` should be in lowercase, So you should try as below :-

```
string actualSubject = driver.FindElement(By.Id("subject-field")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Or using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present on `DOM` as below :

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("subject-field")));
string actualSubject = element.GetAttribute("value");
```

I have tested it and it works for me.

Hope it helps...:)